# htaccess file not working for forwarded port

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, redirect

Good day all,

apologies if this question was already asked/answered - I double-checked it but could not find anything related.

I managed to edit the .htaccess file to disallow listing a particular directory within my /var/www/html folder:

Options -Indexes

it works fine when I try to access using the full path but, as the folder can also be accessed using a redirected port (8080), users can still list files. Am I missing something here?

So, for example:

http://www.example1.com/utils  --> It works
http://www.example1.com:8080 --> Doesn't work

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And if you add the directive to the directory in your  site.conf file rather than using .htaccess?  you should always put as much info into the conf file as possible and delete .htaccess files, as they add a lot of delay in your server response
a little why link
https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/likeapache-htaccess/